# Multiple update forms for one model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, actioncontroller

I want to have multiple forms on one page. Let's make an example to understand what I want:

I have a page for my admins, let's say it's the `admins#show` page. My admin has to change his name on one form on this page and on another form his age. I know I could create one form but I want to have multiple forms (because this is just an example). So my `admins#show` page looks something like this:

```
<%= form_for @admin do |a| %>
    <%= a.label :name %>
    <%= a.text_field :name %>
    <%= a.submit "Submit name change" %>
<% end %>

<%= form_for @admin do |e| %>
    <%= e.label :age %>
    <%= e.number_field :age %>
    <%= e.submit "Submit age change" %>
<% end %>
```

But in my controller, I don't know really how this works and here is my problem. I think I have something like this, but how could I divide the form inputs in the update method?:

```
def edit
    @admin = Admin.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @admin= Admin.find(params[:id])
    if @admin.update_attributes(:name=> admin_params1[:name])
        redirect_to @admin
    else
        render 'edit'
    end

    if @admin.update_attributes(:age=> admin_params2[:age])
        redirect_to @admin
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end


private

def admin_params1
    params.require(:admin).permit(:name)
end

def admin_params2
    params.require(:admin).permit(:age)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I think you could create other non-REST methods in the controller and then add named routes in your config/routes then add your two different forms similar to this;

```
<%= form_for :admin_name, url: admin_name_path, method: :post do |a| %>
    <%= a.label :name %>
    <%= a.text_field :name %>
    <%= a.submit "Submit name change" %>
<% end %>

<%= form_for :admin_age, url: admin_age_path, method: :post do |e| %>
    <%= e.label :age %>
    <%= e.number_field :age %>
    <%= e.submit "Submit age change" %>
<% end %>
```

Then something like this;

```
def update_age
    @admin = Admin.find(params[:admin_age][:id])
    if params[:admin_age]
        @admin.update_attributes(:age=> params[:admin_age][:age])
        redirect_to @admin
    else
        render 'edit'
    end

end

def update_name
    @admin = Admin.find(params[:admin_name][:id])
    if params[:admin_name]
        @admin.update_attributes(:name=> params[:admin_name][:name])
        redirect_to @admin
    else
        render 'edit'
    end

end
```

** not tested for bugs

Answer (score 3):

Its a bit **Unorthodox** what you are doing, but as you **insisted** and only its an **example**, I guess you can handle the **`update`** method by doing like this

```
def update
  @admin= Admin.find(params[:id])
  if params[:commit] == "Submit name change"
    if @admin.update_attributes(admin_params1)
      redirect_to @admin
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  elsif params[:commit] == "Submit age change"
    if @admin.update_attributes(admin_params2)
      redirect_to @admin
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
end
```

**Note:** Not Tested!

Comment: Just a note, :commit is the button name. I am telling this because I couldn't figure out what it is for 10 minutes :D