# Multiple update forms on different pages Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to separate my `update` form on different pages. For example: general, security, account, and etc.

Here are my routes:

```
resources :stores, path: "stores", :as => :stores do
  ...
  match 'admin/settings' => 'stores#settings', via: :get, :as => :settings
  match 'admin/settings/general' => 'stores#general', via: :get, :as => :settings_general
  ...
end
```

Form inside `general` action:

```
= form_for @store, :html => { class: "form", method: :post } do |f|
  = f.text_field :name
  ...
  = f.submit
```

`Stores` controller:

```
def general
  @store = current_user.store
  if @store.update_attributes(params[:store])
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "Successfully."
  else
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "Failed."
  end
end

private 

  def store_params
    params.require(:store).permit(:user_id, :name)
  end
```

For some reason, every time when I click `submit` it redirects me to `update` action (page). I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24105785/multiple-update-forms-for-one-model) but it didn't work for me either.

Tried to change my form to:

```
= form_for @store, url: store_settings_general_path, :html => { class: "form", method: :post } do |f|
   ...
```

but it doesn't perform an action. In other words, this form doesn't update values.

I also tried to do some research but haven't found anything about this problem. What am I doing wrong? Thank you very much.

**UPDATE:**

Console output on `update`:

```
Started POST "/stores/10/admin/settings/general" for ::1 at 2019-07-24 03:59:21 -0400
Processing by StoresController#general as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ubak3tAazQoohB4u6EjFfFufb5HN7T6YBSdFjxhUtVEWHhTzfmUmqvdqYRpvrVolWrNrg5ZtaDyHMc+0JT2cdQ==", "store"=>{"name"=>"THIS IS A NEW NAME"}, "commit"=>"Update Store", "store_id"=>"10"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Store Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "stores".* FROM "stores" WHERE "stores"."user_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["user_id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering stores/general.html.haml within layouts/seller
  Rendered stores/general.html.haml within layouts/seller (4.6ms)
  Rendered global/_navbar.html.haml (11.5ms)
  Rendered global/_stores-sidebar.html.haml (5.5ms)
Filter chain halted as :stores_admin_layout rendered or redirected
Completed 200 OK in 138ms (Views: 135.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

Please note, that the `name` value is a NEW value, however it doesn't update the values inside the `stores` table.

Form in `general`:

```
= form_for @store, url: store_settings_general_path, :html => { class: "form", method: :post } do |f|
```

Comment: I think you have no route via post in your route.rb

Comment: @evgeniy_trebin I tried to add `via: [:get, :post]`, still didn't work. Moreover, I tried to add the same method to the form.. Thank you

Comment: What is the URL generated by `form_for @store`?

Comment: @jvillian `update_store_path`. If I use the first variation of my form, I am getting an error: `Missing template stores/update...` because I don't have an `update` page.

Comment: There is not magic here. The problem is in your routes, try to add standard CRUD routes to your routes.rb and actions to your controller.

Comment: No, I mean what is the generated URL in your HTML. I expect it will be `/stores/1` (or whatever your `@store.id` is).

Comment: @jvillian `...:3000/stores/10/admin/settings/general`. After `submit` it redirects to: `...:3000/stores/10`

Comment: Can you add your console output to your question when you submit to `stores/10/admin/settings/general`, please?

Comment: What is this: `Filter chain halted as :stores_admin_layout rendered or redirected`?

Comment: @jvillian I am using a different layout for this page, which is `store` and I have a method inside my `StoresController` called `seller_admin_layout` where I render my new layout: `render(:layout => "layouts/store")`

Comment: @jvillian thank you very much, I got my mistake. `:stores_admin_layout` was a problem. Thank you very much for your help and time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks, from the comments, that you got to the bottom of things. FWIW, a couple of other notes...

Your route declarations seem a bit archaic. I think I would do:

```
resources :stores do
  member do
    patch 'admin/settings',         action: :settings,  as: :settings
    patch 'admin/settings/general', action: :general,   as: :settings_general
  end
end
```

Which seems, IMO, a little more modern and will give you:

```
         settings_store PATCH  /stores/:id/admin/settings(.:format)               stores#settings
 settings_general_store PATCH  /stores/:id/admin/settings/general(.:format)       stores#general
                 stores GET    /stores(.:format)                                  stores#index
                        POST   /stores(.:format)                                  stores#create
              new_store GET    /stores/new(.:format)                              stores#new
             edit_store GET    /stores/:id/edit(.:format)                         stores#edit
                  store GET    /stores/:id(.:format)                              stores#show
                        PATCH  /stores/:id(.:format)                              stores#update
                        PUT    /stores/:id(.:format)                              stores#update
                        DELETE /stores/:id(.:format)                              stores#destroy
```

You might want to read up on [PUT vs PATCH](https://www.google.com/search?q=rails+patch+vs+post). Given that, in your `general` action, you are updating `@store`, I went with PATCH.

I would also take a look at how you're using [form_for](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for). I believe you *may not* need to use `:html => {}`, here:

```
= form_for @store, :html => { class: "form", method: :post } do |f|
```

You *might* be able to do:

```
= form_for settings_general_store_path(@store), class: 'form' do |f|
```

I can't remember if Rails is smart enough to submit with 'PATCH' when you provide `@store`, so you *might* need to do:

```
= form_for settings_general_store_path(@store), class: 'form', method: :patch do |f|
```

But, give it a go and see what happens.

In your `general` action:

```
def general
  @store = current_user.store
  if @store.update_attributes(params[:store])
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "Successfully."
  else
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "Failed."
  end
end
```

I'm not sure why you're using `params[:store]` when you've gone through the trouble of defining `store_params`. So, I would do something more like:

```
def general
  @store = current_user.store
  if @store.update_attributes(store_params)
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "Successfully."
  else
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "Failed."
  end
end
```